1999 nissan altima throttle relearn or rest procedure
I have a 1999 Nissan Altima that after two years finally will start again with some determination. Once it fires off, it sounds great for a second then the throttle surges up and down. I need to know if there is a relearn procedure for the 1999. I'm not sure if its an electronic Carb or not. I mean it has two cables. I have had the battery removed and reinstalled or recharged several times and that would not rest it. It will surge without touching the foot-feet and if you watch the cables they also don't move when it surges. Can anyone help me out here? Thanks a ton for any help you can provide.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
